# Как отправить файл с помощью бота в телеграм

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Файл я отправлять умею, но есть проблемка. Когда бот отправляет файл он указывает не коренное название файла, а "document" это не удобно.
Знаю, что такой вопрос уже задавался, но способ с filename="file.doc" у меня не работает
Код:

````
bot = telebot.TeleBot("Токен")



@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def echo_all(message):
    with open("game.zip","rb") as file:
        f=file.read()

    bot.send_document(message.chat.id,f,"game.zip")


bot.polling()```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKAsk.jpg
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте передавать объект файла прямо внутри метода `send_document`.
У меня следующий код отлично работает и присылает документ именно с таким именем, с каким он хранится в системе:

```
bot.send_document(message.chat.id, open(r'Путь_к_документу/Название_документа.txt, 'rb'))
```